# Algorithm to order a combination of 2 items

Tags: algorithm, math

I have 5 mathematical problems to be solved and 30 people which will attempt to solve each of these problems.

I know how fast each of the persons is able to solve a certain problem as such:

Person1 will be able to solve ProblemA in 5 secs, B in 7, C in 20 and D in 2mins.

Only one person can work on a problem at once.

Is there any algorithm that can help me determine the order in which i have to program these people in order to get the shortest `golbal` or `overall` solving time?

Comment: At this moment problem looks like assignment one, Are there additional conditions?

Comment: @MBo, no there aren't any other conditions but the tricky part is : consider that i have one problem solver who is the fastest of all. I'll send him to problem A and the difference between him and the next fastest one let s say it's 1 minute. For problem B, if the difference between my fastest solver and the next one is greater than 1 minute, the logical choice would then be to send the prodigy to B and the second best option to A

Comment: Do you know about Dynamic programming and Bit mask technique?

Comment: What are `global` and `overall` solving times?

Comment: Seems I was unclear:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: I guess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling is also relevant here

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmics:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

You have a tree with 5 levels (problems-stages). It is something like combinatory. You will be trying each combination and saving the best time. Once you have one time and the current combination is greater than it you will backtrack and try other alternative discarding by the way some of them (lets say, discarding branches of the combinational tree).

You can improve performance doing some preprocesing upon the elements (persons), ordering them in a way where the most probable combinations are first examined. 
You can order each group of candidates withe the best timers first. One of the conditions of backtracking could be IsSolvingOtherProblem bool.

You will have the best optimal solution with other alternatives but this one will get you to what you want and it will not take ages.